# Recursively change element type with jQuery, why it's partially working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Source node:

```
 <div class="tree">
    <div class="item"><!-- replaced OK -->
        <a href class="toggle">+</a>
        <a href class="name">Name</a>
        <div class="collapse">
            <div class="item"><!-- this wouldn't be replaced ?! --></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"></div><!-- replaced OK -->
</div>
```

I need to clone this node and **recursively replace each** `<div class="item">` with `<li class="item">` and `<div class="collapse">` with `<ul class="collapse">`.

For items, this will work for the first level only:

```
var $clone = $('.tree').clone(false);

$clone
    .find('.item')
    .replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<li>'+$(this).html()+'</li>');
    });
```

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: You replaced the body of the `item`. Thus the inside `item` doesn't exist anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

Your replace with function will replace the html inside the first `.item` with new html elements. So the other `.item` in the array returned by `.find()` does not exist anymore. You can put this in a while loop, so all `.item`s are replaced by `li`s:

```
var $items=$clone.find(".item");
while($items.length>0){
    $items.replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<li>'+$(this).html()+'</li>');
    });
    $items=$clone.find(".item");
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j14f0bx9/

Answer (score 0):

You can search on your `.tree` and replace each `.item` like that (I've removed `$clone`):

```
$('.tree').find($('.item')).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).replaceWith($("<li>").append($(this).contents()));
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/k3g5783b/